# "Variable * is not defined" in an unfindable part of code?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am fairly new to Flash. I have a stage up with a simple button; the `Instance Name` is `init`. My `.as` script (`MainTimeline`) is accessed externally from the stage:

`./Project/MyFlash.fla`

`./Project/MyFlash_fla/MainTimeline.as`

I am linking to the `.as` by setting the `stage` property, `Class`, to `MyFlash_fla.MainTimeline`. The button's, `init`, label is set in the properties to "ENTER".

However, I am coming across this error: `ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable init is not defined.` `at MyFlash_fla::MainTimeline/__setProp_init_Scene1_Layer1_0()` `at MyFlash_fla::MainTimeline()`. I've never seen, nor am able to find, `__setProp_init_Scene1_Layer1_0()`..

This is my current code:

```
    function MainTimeline(){
        this.init.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, begin);
    }
    function begin(event:Event){
        addFrameScript(0, frame1);
    }
```

The functionality is simple; when `MOUSE_UP`, execute `begin`. Everything seems to work fine, except the error mentioned seems to be causing some problems with loading my presets that I set in the properties. The label, instead of `ENTER` as I have set it, changes to `Label`, as if I have not set it. I believe it has something to do with that error, but I have no idea how to access that area or how to fix this. It seems the currently plausible work-around is setting the label in the code, which I prefer not to do, as I plan on including more buttons, checkboxes, etcetera, and that would become a hassle to look at. Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Just FYI: "unreachable code" normally means code that can never be executed, not code that you can't find the source for.

Comment: I know. Conflicting wording, I guess, but that's the first description that came to mind. Editing. :)

Comment: why do you ask exactly the same question when one is marked as answered? ... possible duplicate of [How do I call a button instance in an external .as script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382734/how-do-i-call-a-button-instance-in-an-external-as-script)

Comment: Why do you want to manually add scripts to the frame? Use Document Class instead.

Comment: @PatrickS; That was a separate issue I tended to consistently update to prevent the need to create an entirely new solution, but I figured it'd be simpler to create two separate questions for two separate issues rather than cluttering them together. It was not answered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your "init" instance is not instantiated , __setProp_init_Scene1_Layer1_0() is behind the scenes code, don't worry about this.

You may have to either declare the init variable

```
     //assuming your button is a MovieClip
     private var init:MovieClip;

     function MainTimeline()
     {
         init.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, begin);
     }
```

or, instead of directly adding it to the stage, link it to its own class using "Export for Actionscript" in the properties panel & add it on the code side. I generally prefer this approach as it gives you more control over your display objects. Of course , since it's not added to the stage , you won't need an instance name!

```
     private var button:MovieClip = new init();

     function MainTimeline()
     {
         button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, begin);
     }
```

On a side note, "init" may not be the best name for a button, since it's often used in classes as a method name...

Comment: When trying your second solution, I set the `Class` property of the button to `ctrl`, followed by this code:

    var button:MovieClip = new ctrl();
    function MainTimeline(){
        button.addEventListener(..., ...);
    }
    ...

With this, I get no error, but the button flashes as described above. :S It is set as a `MovieClip`.

Comment: You should try to debug with another MovieClip. Draw a Shape, convert it to a MovieClip then try the second solution... if it works, there's a problem with your button

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help, Patrick. I've created a green square, converted it to `Symbol`, giving it the `Class` of `testing`, and the `Base Class` preset at `flash.display.MovieClip`. Within my code, I added `var test:MovieClip = new testing();` and within `MainTimeline`, `test.visible = false;` to test if it had any control over the property, to no avail. For the sake of trying, I also tried adding the event listener with no luck. There are no errors, but nothing happens either.

Comment: :) No error is good! why did you set test.visible to false? try instead to change the x & y properties and check if your object is displayed. If you can see it, then go back to your button MovieClip and try to debug it, because that's probably where the problem is

Comment: I've eliminated the problem. Not solved, though. I simply removed the property from my `stage` linking to the external .as script and pasted the code with a few edits in frame1's action. It's working now. :) Currently messing with RadioButtons and figuring out how to add an event listener to them without having to define each one with an instance name.. but that's another thing. :) Thanks for your help, Patrick.

Comment: hmmm... moving the code onto the Actions frame doesn't sound ideal... thx for accepting the answer but sorry i couldn't help more... it may be worth asking the question differently, showing more of your code and letting us know what it is you'd like to achieve in more details.

Answer (score 0):

For other readers, the above error probably means that you need to go to

- File/Publish Settings/ AS3.0 Settings(looks like a wrench in the upper
  right)

and then set **"Automatically declare stage instances"** checkbox to checked. Also, uncheck "strict mode" just in case it is checked and the file continues to produce errors.